# Can't draw inside cube - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, drawing

I've created this cube with only 3 faces and I want to draw a letter inside it, but if I try to call the function with "glutDisplayFunc(drawA);", it displays a blank window, and if I want to call the function drawA();, it doesn't display the letter, but it displays the cube...

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

glutCreateWindow("Tema2");

glutDisplayFunc(Display);
//glutDisplayFunc(drawA);
//drawA();
glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
glutMotionFunc(Motion);

Init();

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}



void drawA() {
  glBegin(GL_LINES);

  glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //green

  glVertex3f(-0.2, -0.5, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(0.0, 0.4, -0.5);
  glVertex3f(0.2, -0.5, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(0.0, 0.4, -0.5);

  glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `glutDisplayFunc` is not to actually draw something, but to tell GLUT which function should be called, when the need to redraw the window contents arises.

If you want to draw something you just draw it; ideally you do this from the function registered as display function which will get called in response to a window display request.